# Webpack-dev-server HMR not working with multiple entry points

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

today I've noticed a strange bug (or I am to dumb?) with my webpack-dev-server.

I've got a Spring Boot App with thymleaf templates. Some pages may only load one others may have more than one js-file:

```js
// main.js
import "../style.scss";
```

```html
single.html:
<body>
  <script th:src="@{/myapp/js/main.js}"></script>
</body>

multiple.html
<body>
  <script th:src="@{/myapp/js/main.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/myapp/js/other.js}"></script>
</body>
```

I've splitted my config into a dev, production and common part:

`webpack.common.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/main/js/main.js"),
        other: path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/main/js/other.js"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/resources/static/myapp"),
        filename: "js/[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            // prettier-ignore
                            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                                corejs: "3.6.4",
                                // debug: true,
                                useBuiltIns: "usage"
                            }
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "css/[name].css",
        }),
    ],
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```js
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "/": "http://localhost:8081",
        },
        port: 8083,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: "/myapp",
        },
    },
});
```

The strange behaviour: If I'm editing files for the page which only a single script has been loaded (`single.html`), changes are applied immediately. For example changing the background color in the css file is displayed without pagereload. If I'm editing a page where multiple scripts (entry points) are used this is not working anymore. My dev-console logs the following:

> [HMR] Update failed: Loading hot update chunk global failed.
> (missing: http://localhost:8083/myapp/main.618757b0411fc5552e94.hot-update.js)

The first entry point / chunk (`main.js`) cannot be loaded, caused by the hash? I need to manually refresh the whole page, to apply changes. I've already searched for solutions and tried to apply this [tip](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk)

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'single',
  },
}
```

However my dev console does not log any HMR output anymore and nothing happens. It seems like HMR has stopped working in my browser. Webpack is running and bundling it correctly!

Any ideas? Thanks so far and apologizes for this wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

The `optimization.runtimeChunk` option should be `true` or `'single'` and not an object with `name`:

```js
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
```

[As the documentation explains](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) this is an alias for:

```js
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'runtime',
    },
  },
```

Also, you'll want to **include the `runtime.js` file on the page**, however you need to do that for your set up. It should only be served in the dev environment (so for example, if `NODE_ENV` is `"development"`).

---

In my case I have production, server-side script files alongside webpack-dev-server, and needed this option enabled so it would correctly serve `runtime.js` from the manifest.json:

```js
  devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
  }
```